# Why is "Let There Be Range" so expensive ? Is it worth that money?

Tags: nlhe, rules, books, let-there-be-range

I saw [this](http://www.dailyvariance.com/poker-books/let-there-be-range/) book on the Internet today called *one of the best poker books*. Price is unbelievable. **$947.00**

[image]

I made some little search and I found this comment.

> Very expensive, but again, there are no bad reviews on this book. If
>   you have the money and you are very serious about your game, this
>   would be a wise investment. Advanced and serious players only of
>   course.

Does anyone read this book before? What is this books' *magic*?

Comment: here is another thread about it in case you're still interested
http://www.runitonce.com/chatter/let-there-be-range/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a serious poker book, this isn't the most expensive I've seen. Shootaa (Reid Young) has a book out for around $5k and when it came out it honestly may have been worth the price. The fact is that these tips will allow you to improve your game so much that you'll make more than the price of book in a relatively short period of time. Granted, this is assuming you're already a mid-high stakes player (or for the case of this book, small-mid stakes).

Previously, and this is probably still the case but I've stopped playing because of Black Friday, the best ways to learn were to watch training videos, learn through forums such as this one, and discuss hands with players who are better than yourself. If you still have a lot to learn, books like these may not help you much. But at the end of the day if you're struggling at 100nl with a 2bb/100 winrate, this sort of book could potentially help you quite a bit.

I confess that I have no knowledge of the book you've mentioned but decided to answer the more general question of why poker books can be so expensive. Another poster mentioned that books from well known (and he would argue, more credible) poker pros are much cheaper. The fact of the matter is that these books are

a) severely outdated
b) written mostly by **live** players who have little to no experience playing online
c) written by players who are famous and not necessarily skilled

Doyle Brunson is obviously a great poker player; however, I'd much sooner take the advice of a winning 400nl reg than him when it comes to online (and possibly live, but that's another argument) games.

Answer (score 9):

There's no way such a price makes any sense. With that money, you can get 20 or 30 other books written by world famous and world champion players; with the help of those books you will definitely improve your game if you're serious about doing it.

No matter how good it is, the price is just unjustified. I don't know if I remember correctly, but I think not even the first edition of Super System was that expensive.

I wouldn't buy it. And I wouldn't advise anyone else to buy it, even if they're swimming in money.

PS: It's only 170 pages, that's $5.50 per page. It's just too much...

Answer (score 5):

There's a thread about that book [here](http://www.cardschat.com/f13/let-there-range-180911/).  Seems like it came out in 2008, so the contents and strategies have probably already percolated through the serious, high-dollar players.

Answer (score 5):

Oh yeah, it's got decent content in it, but nothing you won't find if you search through the twoplustwo high stakes forums pretty diligently.  Also, no one can put the skills in your brain FOR you.  You have to be willing to dig heavily into the math and game theory yourself.  The book, "The Mathematics of Poker" is really good for this.

Answer (score 2):

This book was revolutionary when it was released because it was the first to correctly demonstrate how to do EV calcs against a range of hands.  That information is widely available now however.  So the book is not really worth so much today.  At the time of release though it was worth that much to mid stakes professionals looking to improve their strategies.

Answer (score 1):

I have read the book completely. You really need some math knowledge and understanding to be able to follow everything completely. Also, you need to be able to understand the English language enough to be able to understand everything clearly.
Is the book worth the price? In my opinion not. However, if you are already on a high level and playing semi professional, this might be just the book you are looking for. The thing is, everything is stated with clear examples and there is not really such a nice and complete manual in what the book explains (equity, ...).